# Ellipsize text within switch in android

Tags: ellipsis, android-switch

I have a switch and i need the text within the switch(Eg: ON/OFF) to be ellipsized if long.
How can it be done?The following does not work!!

```
<Switch
                android:id="@+id/switch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:minWidth="80dp"
                android:minHeight="18dp"
                android:textOff="@string/toggle_off"
                android:textOn="@string/toggle_on"
                android:ellipsize:end
                android:maxWidth="50dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                 >
            </Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your java file:

```
    Switch switch = (Switch) vi.findViewById(R.id.switch);
    switch.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
    switch.setSingleLine(true);
```